# How can I fix or stop moisture damage caused by the kitchen sink?

Tags: kitchens, sink

So we recently moved into a new place and it seems like the kitchen faucet use to leak at some stage and that the previous owners did fix this, but now behind the kitchen sink by the tiles, there is some kind of a moisture problem. It does have a white seal or something similar on, but this is also starting to come loose. Is there anyway to repair this damage or patch it up?

Comment: your question is pretty vague. Can you post a picture or more accurately describe the "white seal" and what kind of moisture damage.

Comment: Are you referring to the caulking?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes when water or moisture gets trapped under or behind something it can linger for a long time and may not dry out until it is exposed to open air, yes, just about anything can be repaired that is water damaged

Answer (score 0):

**If there is still an ongoing moisture problem under your sink, then your sink is still leaking.** If its a slight moisture problem (rather than a dramatic noticable leak when you turn on the faucet) then it's probably actually the drainage pipe which is leaking.  Fill your sink with water, then check your drainage pipe.  If its dry, then drain the sink completely and check the drainage pipe again.  If it's is wet after this experiment then its definitely a drainage issue.  If so, I recommend tightly wrapping black electrical tape around all the joint-connectors of the drainage pipe and calling a plumber when you have a few hundred bucks available to get it fixed.